# Running .bat file through Task Scheduler doesn't work, however when running the .bat file manually it works

Tags: java, task, scheduler

Running .bat file through task scheduler gives error:

Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

Tried below steps but still the error:
1. Removed java.exe, javaw.exe, javawx.exe from system 32 and sysWOW64 folder
2. changed current version of java fro 1.8 to 1.7

It run when I click on the .bat file manually.

Any suggestion to resolve the issue?

Comment: The Task Scheduler may be running as a different user, you may wish to provide more details about how it's setup and how it runs

Comment: 1. General - Run only when user is logged on         2. Trigger - Weekly    3. Action - Start a program: choose the location where .bat file is there

Comment: Can you add the contents of the bat?

Comment: bat files contains various jar files.                                                          
 cd C:\SM9 Suspension

java -jar Delete.jar > Deletelog.txt
java -jar Filedownloadnew.jar > Filedownloadnewlog.txt
java -jar ReadExcelcopynew.jar > ReadExcellog.txt